# Losing StandardSetController selected records with first visit to VF page

Tags: visualforce, session, standardsetcontroller, platform-bug

I have a VF page that leverages a custom object's StandardSetController to compare records. I created a custom button to allow users to select records of that object from a related list and compare them with the click of a button.

With every new session, `StandardSetController.getSelected()` comes up empty the very first time I click the button to open the VF page. All subsequent requests are fine.

It appears to be related to the passing of the session details to VF because there's a very quick redirect to `<base_url>/visualforce/session/` before seeing the VF page. To confirm this, I embedded an empty VF page into the standard layout of the page that contains the related list, and things work as expected.

Is this a bug? Any other solutions to get around this issue besides the one above?

Comment: Please add the code for your Visualforce page into the question.

Comment: Man, that's weird, I'm inclined to say that's a bug based on the troubleshooting you've done.

Answer (score 2):

The Standardsetcontroller was returning empty list of records for ListView button which was redirecting to VF page.
Deactivated the critical update “Enhanced Session ID Management for Visualforce” and it resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I don't see that option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue and I was able to resolve it!

The issue is with the button, you are using URL. Try changing it to Visual Force Page and it will work as expected.

Hope this works for you!